# How to properly bind Image

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I made a grid with 3 rows and 3 columns, to bind the images to it. I have a List with objects of type Post. I want to bind the images of that List to the grid. What is the proper way to do it?

Code:

```
 <ScrollViewer Height="400" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Posts}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                                <ListBox.ItemsPanel >
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <UniformGrid Rows="3" Columns="3"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                <Image Source="{Binding File}"></Image> <!-- Here I want to bind the image but it throws me exception: InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead. -->



                            </ListBox>
                        </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since each ListBoxItem will have a Post item as it's DataContext, You can make an DataTemplate for the ListBox.
It will be it's ItemTemplate(under a property of the same name).
In it, you can bind an Image's Source property to the image in your Post object.

Answer (score 0):

The `Source` binding in wpf is image path, so either you make a binding path string to image source or you make it be a static resouce for accessing.

1. Binding Path

```xml
<Image Source="{Binding DisplayedImagePath}" />
```

Either in Property or ViewModel

```
public string DisplayedImage 
{
    get { return "pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Images/YourImage.png"; }
}
```

2. Static Resouce

```xml
<BitmapImage x:Key="MyImageSource"
 UriSource="pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Images/YourImage.png" />
```

Then in your code:

```xml
<Image Source="{StaticResource MyImageSource}" />
```